# Is it possible to produce hydrogen sulfide with tap water and activated carbon or CuZn?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, redox

Please note I'm a bit out of my depth with chemistry.

**The situation:**
I have a [KDF](http://www.kdfft.com/HowItWorks.htm)/GAC water filter that defies logic and releases $\ce{H2S}$ (assuming it by smell/taste) in the water after filtration.

Is it possible that some reaction could produce $\ce{H2S}$ with water and $\ce{CuZn}$ media (such as [KDF](http://www.kdfft.com/HowItWorks.htm)) or GAC (Granulized Activated Carbon).

The more practical problem:
[DIY Exchange - KDF Filter Question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/133418/why-does-a-new-kdf-gac-filter-cause-a-rotten-egg-smell-taste)

Comment: On the link about those filters it says that they remove H2S not release it. The filter contains Cu and Zn so there is no sulphur source in there. The activated carbon is just carbon so no sulphur in there either and as you say your water is fine before it goes through the filter. There is no chance that the filter is generating H2S unless it has been used and it got saturated with H2S or other sulphur source. Just send it back, get a refund, and get another one.

Comment: @AMM Thanks for your comment, I agree it could be saturated, however I doubt it to be the cause. I was wondering if there is maybe some salt like PbSO4 and some other chemicals that could react in a way with the C, Cu or Zn as catalysts or as partakers to create H2S (or something that smells as bad). Also my question here is mainly for academic purposes and understanding the world we live in.

Comment: It still doenst make any sense because in order to get H2S you need to reduce SO4-2 from +6 to -2 which means that you need to go through the 0 oxidation state first meaning that you ll be having sulphur formation which will precipitate out of the solution, and anyway the filter shoul be oxidizing S-2 anions to elemental S. What does the supplier suggest is happening? This is odd.

Comment: @AMM thanks it makes sense. Yup, very odd. The supplier have not yet responded to my mail (they probably think I'm crazy haha).

Comment: What is "Ze"  ???

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C Pretty sure he means Zn. It is a Zn/Cu filter.

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C haha, fixed it thx. Meant Zn.